# Problema a la hora de querer guardar en la base de datos con Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

Estoy tratando de con un formulario poder guardar en 2 bases de datos distintas, una base de datos asociada con el modelo Persona y otra con el modelo User usando la autenticación de Laravel 8.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    $datos= ['nombre' => $data['name'],'apellido' => $data['surname'],'cedula' => $data['cedula'],'email' => $datos['email'],
    'telefono' =>$datos['telefono'],'direccion' =>$datos['direccion'],'ciudadResi' =>$datos['ciudadResi'],'genero' =>$datos['genero'],]; 

    Persona::create($datos)([
        'nombre' => $datos['nombre'],
        'apellido' => $datos['apellido'],
        'cedula' => $datos['cedula'],
        'email' => $datos['email'],
        'telefono' =>$datos['telefono'],
        'direccion' =>$datos['direccion'],
        'ciudadResi' =>$datos['ciudadResi'],
        'fechaNacimiento' =>'1998-03-05',
        'genero' =>$datos['genero'],
        'estado'=> '1',
        'idTipoPersona'=>'2'
    ]);
    
    User::create($data)([
        'name' => 'clienteUser',
        'surname' => $data['surname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'nick' => $data['nick'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'role' => 'client'
    ]);
}
```

Esto dentro del RegisterController, el problema es que cuando trato de ejecutar ese código me dice que la variable $datos no está definida. Lo que deseo hacer es coger los valores del formulario que estan en $data menos el created_at y el updated_at que se crean automáticamente con Laravel y ponerlos en la variable $datos porque esos son los valores que necesita la tabla personas, User debe coger solo los valores que ahí tengo en el metodo. Muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Por qué haces esto: `create($datos)`?

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer así

```
Persona::create([
        'nombre' => $datos['nombre'],
        'apellido' => $datos['apellido'],
        'cedula' => $datos['cedula'],
        'email' => $datos['email'],
        'telefono' =>$datos['telefono'],
        'direccion' =>$datos['direccion'],
        'ciudadResi' =>$datos['ciudadResi'],
        'fechaNacimiento' =>'1998-03-05',
        'genero' =>$datos['genero'],
        'estado'=> '1',
        'idTipoPersona'=>'2'
    ]);
```

o tambien así

```
Persona::create($datos);
```

Comment: Igual si checas [answer], editas y explicas tu aporte le será mas claro al autor de la pregunta